# How does backup deal with existing snapshots in snapshot based backup

Tags: backup, virtualization, netbackup

I have a question regarding backups and VM's that contain snapshots. If i have a VM running in vmware with 2 snapshots and a snapshot based backup runs overnight, will it delete all of my snapshots or will it only delete the one it creates during the process?

Comment: It depends on the backup solution. What product are you using? Also Snapshots are BAD.

Comment: I know snapshots are bad, i'm preaching it as well. This is a bit of an odd situation for me as well. The solution in question is netbackup. I never used netback up and someone made me question what i already know. I didnt have much luck finding info myself so decided to ask on here.

Comment: Are you using the Host backup or Agent backup of the guest?

Comment: Host backup, no agent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetBackup uses the VMware Storage API’s and shouldn’t cause issues but;

**VMsnapshots Snapshots are bad!** 
[this is a good explanation why](https://serverfault.com/q/430138/99233)

Snapshots can cause issues and depending on the delta size of the file it may not get played into the backup routine. I have seen issues in the past where chains of snapshots have been missed. I would recommend that you either use agent based processing for these VM’s if you cannot clean the snapshots or export the VM as a template (a better solution if you keeping snapshots for “backup").

Comment: Not all snapshots are bad. It depends on the implementation. ZFS for example excels at snapshots. I know in this instance you're talking about VMware snaps, and I agree with you on that point. However, you need to qualify that you are talking about VMware snapshots, not snapshots in general.